# Fast alternative to SortedMap.mapValues

Tags: performance, scala, data-structures

The following code demonstrates the problem I have (in the real case `SortedMap` keys are Joda `DateTime`, and maps contain several thousands of elements).

```
import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, ObjectOutputStream}

import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

object Main extends App {
  val s = SortedMap(1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C")

  def f(s: String) = s


  val sMap = s.map(kv => kv._1 -> f(kv._2)) // slow: rebuilds Map, as keys could change

  val sMapValues = s.mapValues(f) // fast, but creates a view only

  val so = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(so)
  oos.writeObject(s) // works
  oos.writeObject(sMap) // works
  oos.writeObject(sMapValues) // does not work - view only

  oos.close()
  so.close()
}
```

The problem is while `mapValues` has a good performance for `SortedMap`, the result is not a real collection but a view, and as such it cannot be serialized. The simple solution of mapping both keys and values works, but is slow, as the tree representation is rebuilt, `map` does not know I am not changing the keys.

Is there any fast alternative to `SortedMap.mapValues`, which outputs a serializable result?

Comment: What if you do identity `map` on top of `mapValues`: `sMapValues.map(identity)`, will it still rebuild?

Comment: I suspect that `mapValues(f)` is fast because `f` is applied lazily. Upon serialization, `f` actually needs to be applied, so I think you could as well serialize it with `toSeq` at some stage, either in `oos.writeObject(sMapValues.toSeq)` or in `val sMapValues = s.mapValues(f).toSeq`.

Answer (score 0):

Try transform:

```
val sMapValues = s.transform((_,v) => f(v))
```

Although the key and the value are provided to the transformation lambda, the result is applied only to the value, the key is unchanged.

Comment: Looks promising, however I have checked this in the debugger, `transform` performs a full rebuild: `for ((key, value) <- this) b += ((key, f(key, value)))`.